# How to capitalize textual expressions in property setter?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a c# wpf project. On the View side, the property named NewBook is bound to the text boxes on the ViewModel side. However, the changes I have made in the setter of this property are not reflected in the view side. I want to capitalize string expressions with ConverToTitle method when text boxes lose keyboard focus. But I want to do this via NewBook, not by defining individual properties. Where is my mistake and how can I make this work?
Thanks.

```
internal class NewBookViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        LibraryDataContext Db;
                    
        public RelayCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand CloseWindowCommand { get; }

        private Book _newBook;
        public Book NewBook
        {
get { return _newBook; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _newBook, value);
                NewBook.ConvertToTitle();
                        }
        }

        private int _demirbasNo;
                public int DemirbasNo
        {
            get { return _demirbasNo; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _demirbasNo, value);
                NewBook.Barkod = Barcode.GenerateEAN13BarcodeNumber(_demirbasNo);
                NewBook.DemirbasNo = _demirbasNo;                
            }
        }

        private Author Author;
        private Yayinevi publisher;
        public ObservableCollection<Book> BooklarCollection { get; set; }

        public NewBookViewModel()
        {
            SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveExecute, CanExecuteSaveCommand);
            CloseWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(CloseExecute);
            Db = new LibraryDataContext();

NewBook = new Book();
            DemirbasNo= BookService.NextDemirbaşNo();
            NewBook.Barkod = Barcode.GenerateEAN13BarcodeNumber(_demirbasNo);
        }

        private bool CanExecuteSaveCommand() => true;
        
        private void SaveExecute()
        {
            BookValidator validator= new BookValidator();
            ValidationHelper<Book> validationHelper = new ValidationHelper<Book>(validator);
            MessagePublisher.SendMessage(validationHelper.ErrorMessage(NewBook),MessageType.Error);
                  
            /* AuthorCheck(newBook.Authori.AdiSoyadi);
PublisherCheck(newBook.Yayinevi.Adi);
            BookService<Book> BookService = new BookService<Book>();
            BookService.Add(newBook);
            BookService.SaveChanges();
            
            CloseExecute(); */
        }
      
        private void  CloseExecute()
        {
            var activeWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<BaseWindow>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.IsActive);
            if (activeWindow != null)
            {
                activeWindow.Close();
            }

        }
    }

public static void ConvertToTitle<t>(this t obj)
        {
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = typeof(t).GetProperties();
            
            foreach (var property in propertyInfo)
            {
                if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    string value = (string)property.GetValue(obj);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    {
                        property.SetValue(obj, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(value));
                    }
                                    }                
            }
                    }
    }

internal class NewBookViewModel : ObservableObject
{
LibraryDataContext Db;

public RelayCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
public RelayCommand CloseWindowCommand { get; }

private Book _newBook;
public Book NewBook
{
get { return _newBook; }
set
{
SetProperty(ref _newBook, value);
NewBook.ConvertToTitle();
}
}

private int _demirbasNo;
public int DemirbasNo
{
get { return _demirbasNo; }
set
{
SetProperty(ref _demirbasNo, value);
NewBook.Barkod = Barcode.GenerateEAN13BarcodeNumber(_demirbasNo);
NewBook.DemirbasNo = _demirbasNo;
}
}

private Author Author;
private Yayinevi publisher;
public ObservableCollection<Book> BooklarCollection { get; set; }

public NewBookViewModel()
{
SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveExecute, CanExecuteSaveCommand);
CloseWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(CloseExecute);
Db = new LibraryDataContext();

NewBook = new Book();
DemirbasNo= BookService.NextDemirbaşNo();
NewBook.Barkod = Barcode.GenerateEAN13BarcodeNumber(_demirbasNo);
}

private bool CanExecuteSaveCommand() => true;

private void SaveExecute()
{
BookValidator validator= new BookValidator();
ValidationHelper<Book> validationHelper = new ValidationHelper<Book>(validator);
MessagePublisher.SendMessage(validationHelper.ErrorMessage(NewBook),MessageType.Error);

/* AuthorCheck(newBook.Authori.AdiSoyadi);
PublisherCheck(newBook.Yayinevi.Adi);
BookService<Book> BookService = new BookService<Book>();
BookService.Add(newBook);
BookService.SaveChanges();

CloseExecute(); */
}

private voidCloseExecute()
{
var activeWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<BaseWindow>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.IsActive);
if (activeWindow != null)
{
activeWindow.Close();
}

}
}

public static void ConvertToTitle<t>(this t obj)
{
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = typeof(t).GetProperties();

foreach (var property in propertyInfo)
{
if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
{
string value = (string)property.GetValue(obj);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
{
property.SetValue(obj, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(value));
}
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your class to inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and invoke a `PropertyChanged` Event in your setter. Something like below:

```
  public class Library: INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      private string name;
      // Declare the event
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public Library()
      {
      }

      public Library(string value)
      {
          this.name = value;
      }

      public string Book
      {
          get { return name; }
          set
          {
              name = value;
              // Change to upper case here
              // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
              OnPropertyChanged();
          }
      }

      // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
      // The calling member's name will be used as the parameter.
      protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
      {
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hello
First of all thank you very much for the help. I don't understand how to implement this class. The Book model class implements INotifyPropertyChange. Also I am using MVVM Community Toolkit SetProperty() in my project. Could you share some more descriptive information?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event for the changed property in order to update the data binding.

First, make sure your data source (in your case `Book`) implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Second, raise the event right after modifying the property:

```cs
public static void ConvertToTitleCase(this INotifyPropertyChanged obj)
{
  Type callerTypeInfo = obj.GetType();
  FieldInfo propertyChangedEventFieldInfo = callerTypeInfo.GetField(nameof(System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged));
  object eventDelegate = propertyChangedEventFieldInfo.GetValue(obj);
  Type eventDelegateTypeInfo = eventDelegate.GetType();
  MethodInfo delegateInvokeMethodInfo = eventDelegateTypeInfo.GetMethod("Invoke");

  PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = callerTypeInfo.GetProperties();
  foreach (var property in propertyInfo)
  {
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
      string value = (string)property.GetValue(obj);
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
      {
        return;
      }
      
      property.SetValue(obj, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(value));
      /* Raise the PropertyChanged event for the current property */
  
      string propertyName = property.Name;
      Type propertyChangedEventArgsTypeInfo = typeof(System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs);
      ConstructorInfo propertyChangedEventArgsConstructorInfo = propertyChangedEventArgsTypeInfo.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
            
      object propertyChangedEventArgsInstance = propertyChangedEventArgsConstructorInfo.Invoke(obj, new[] { propertyName });
      object sender = obj;
      delegateInvokeMethodInfo.Invoke(eventDelegate, new[] { sender, propertyChangedEventArgsInstance });
    }  
  }
}
```

### Remarks

- You should avoid writing extension methods for the type `object` as it will clutter the API and code suggestion list. Because *every* .NET type inherits from `object` all objects would have access to it, even when it doesn't make sense. In this context, the generic type parameter is redundant too, therefore this method must not be a generic method.
  Consider to use a more restrictive type, for example start with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Because we need to raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event `INotifyPropertyChanged` is the minimum required type constraint in order to make the code work:

```cs
public static void ConvertToTitleCase(this INotifyPropertyChanged iNotifyPropertyChangedImplementation)
```

- Consider to implement the character case modification directly in the relevant type. This eliminates the slow and heavy reflection and adds clarity and robustness to your code:

```cs
class Book : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string title;
  public string Title
  {
    get => this.title;
    set
    {
      this.title = ToTitleCase(value);
    }
  }

  public string ToTitleCase(string text)
    => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)
        ? string.Empty
        : CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(text);
}
```

Comment: Hello
First of all, thank you very much. In the following parts, I will use the ConverToTitle method to convert the data received from excel to uppercase. That's why I designed it this way.
I defined it as SetProperty(ref _BookName, Value) in the Book class. I want to handle this in setter if possible in ModelView. The reason is that in the next stages, I will have the job of converting to uppercase according to the user's preference. Finally, I don't want to do capitalization in the model (Book). Can we handle this in ModelView?
Thanks.

Comment: What is "ModelView"? Do you mean Model in terms of MVVM? Because there is no ModelView" in MVVM. There is a View, a View Model and a Model. When you want to change capitalization in the Model than you must do it e.g. before you persist the data e.g. in a database. It's called data normalization, where you transform all data to a common data norm according to specific rules (e.g. first letter must be capitalized, lengths must be in meters etc.

Comment: To convert text received from excel to uppercase or title case consider to let your extension method target `string`. This would be more practical and general and very important it would perform much better than using reflection.. Now you know that there is already the `TextInfo.ToTitleCase` method which makes an extension method redundant.

Comment: Reading from a data source like an Excel file is Model business. So after reading the Excel file you must normalize the relevant text before you handle it over to the View Model. Then the View Model exposes this normalized data to the View to allow the user to view/modify it. Then let the View Model pass the modified data back to the Model. Now before the Model persists the modified data normalize it again (e.g. by calling `TextInfo.ToTitleCase` on all strings).

Comment: Hello
Yes, you are right. I typed wrong. Then I will normalize the data before saving it to the database and save it that way. I could manipulate the object more easily with the Extension Method. But with the string parameter, it will also be necessary to put it into the foreach loop. Could you please write me a method with the method you mentioned?
Thanks.

Comment: IF you are working with a database you should use the database script language to do the task. SQL and SQL derivatives usually support UPPER and LOWER query instructions. Usually you would use a combination of them in order to capitalize only  the first letter. Some databases provide a function to simplify this tasks. It really depends on the database you are using. I suggest to consult the docs to learn about such functions.

Comment: This should be the way to go. Databases are highly optimized. They usually outperform code (that has to be compiled etc.) when it comes to data manipulations or data operations in general and definitely outperform reflection. It's also easier to maintain than reflection code.